# Adding installed pip package to path

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I used pip3 to install the relational algebra tool 'radb'. When I try to use radb my system says command not found. I believe this is because it is not installed to my path.

I looked for the location of the radb folder and it is located in ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Is there some command I can use to add this to my path? I am unfamiliar with how path works so all the other information I've seen has been confusing.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/251038; found in https://superuser.com/search?q=linux+add+to+path

Comment: `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` is a directory with user-installed Python **libraries**, not scripts. **Scripts** are in `~/.local/bin`. Verify there is `~/.local/bin/radb` and run it with full path or with changed `$PATH`. If it's not there ask `pip`: `pip show --files radb`